# calling function to store the result in "this"

Tags: c++

My SortedMerge function is declared as under :

```
sortedMerge(ListOfParts *& l2, ListOfParts *& result);
```

In the below function of the same class, I wish to call this SortedMerge() function using object `tmp1` and get the result in the object that called the mergeSort functionbelow; ie, `this`.
Basically, object l1 in main() calls mergeSort() and from there I get 2 Lists tmp1, tmp2 and now I wish to call SortedMErge to store the RESULT in l1;

Really stuck.  I thought using "this" would suffice, but I think it has some conflict with the function parameter not taking ant CONST and "this" would make it CONST.

So what could be another work around for this?

```
Class ListOfParts{

struct CarPart{

int data;
CarPart *next;

}


CarPart *Head;

public:


    sortedMerge(ListOfParts *& l2, ListOfParts *& result);

void mergeSort(){

    ListOfParts *tmp1;
    ListOfParts *tmp2;
    if(this->Head == NULL || this->Head->Next == NULL){

        return;

    }

    this->frontBackSplit(tmp1, tmp2);

    tmp1->mergeSort();
    tmp2->mergeSort();


    tmp1->sortedMerge(tmp2, this)   
}

}
```

Comment: Hint: When you create a pointer, you don't create an object to which the pointer points.

Answer (score 0):

Change `sortedMerge` to take its arguments by value, not reference:

```
sortedMerge(ListOfParts * l2, ListOfParts * result);
```

Then you'll be able to pass unmodifiable pointers such as `this`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I want to store the sorted list n RESULT and for that I will have to pass by Reference, right?

Comment: @Roger: You're already passing a pointer; the function can modify the list that it's pointing to, which is what you want here. You only need to pass a reference to the pointer if you want the function to update the pointer to refer to a new list - you don't need that,  since `mergeSort` doesn't do anything with the pointers after passing them to `sortedMerge`, and you can't do it anyway, since you can't change what `this` points to.

Comment: what wud be the best option? pass by value is the only?